# Динамическое создание хелперов с помощью самописного шаблонизатора

Tags: php, шаблоны

Здравствуйте! Пишу шаблонизатор на PHP. Шаблонизатор должен реализовывать следущий функционал:

1) Поддержка​ ​лайаута​

2) Возможность​ ​добавить​ ​переменную​

3) Возможность​ ​удаления​ ​переменной​ ​или​ ​очищение​ ​всех​ ​переменных

4) Добавление​ ​хелперов

Первые три пункта я реализовала и все хорошо. Появилась проблема с четвертым пунктом. Не совсем понимаю, как можно реализовать динамическое создание функции.
Буду благодарна за помощь.

Вот код, которые есть на данный момент:

```
    class Template
{
    public $data = [];

    public function setProperty($name, $value) {
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function deleteProperty($name) {
        unset($this->data[$name]);
    }

    public function clearProperties()
    {
        array_walk($this->data, array(&$this, 'clear'));
    }

    public function clear(&$item1)
    {
        $item1 = '';
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        if (isset($this->data[$name])) return $this->data[$name];
        return "";
    }

}
```

Пример создания хелпера такой:

```
$tpl->addHelper('clear',​ ​'htmlentities');
$tpl->addHelper('now',​ ​function(){​ ​return​ ​date('m.d.Y');​ ​});
```

Comment: пример динамического создания функции: `$sqr = create_function('$x', 'return $x * $x;');
echo $sqr(3); // Выведется 9`

Comment: @Эдуард,спасибо за комментарий) Но данная функция считается устаревшей, поэтому ее использовать не желательно если Вы пишите на PHP 7.2

Comment: так в более поздних версиях существуют же так называемые лямбда-функции )

Comment: вы надеетесь по функционалу и эффективности переплюнуть `smarty` и `twig` ?

Comment: @teran, если бы мне надо было использовать готовый шаблонизатор. я бы так и сделала, но, к сожалению, мне надо написать свой.

Comment: @kittycat_13 тот же пример, что выше в комментарии, но под современный пхп: `$sqr = function ($x) {return $x * $x;};

echo $sqr(3); // Выведется 9`

Comment: @Эдуард поскольку у автора есть пример анонимных функций в конце, то видимо их синтаксис и смысл известны

Comment: а в чем собственно сложность то возникает у вас? в массив по имени сохраняйте да и все. сложности с вызовом `$tpl->now()` или с чем?

Comment: @teran, действительно, видимо автор дописал, т.к. изначально его не было.

Comment: @Эдуард, У меня немного не в том проблема. Я просто наверное неправильно объяснила) Вот смотрите. Я могу создать анонимную функцию. Проблема не в этом. Допустим, у меня есть метод addHelper. Я в нем создаю свои анонимные функции. Мне надо их сохранять в переменные, чтобы в шаблоне я могла к этим функциям обращаться вот так: <?=​ ​$this->now();​ ​?

Comment: Вот собственно с этим и проблема.

Comment: Получается свойства я сохраняю в массиве $this->data. А вот как мне в свойство класса сохранить функцию, чтобы потом ее можно было вызвать динамически?

Comment: дак по аналогии с `__get` надо использоать `__call`

Comment: а также и сохранить `$this->_helpers[$name] = $func` в случае анонимок в пхп 7 можно будет вызвать прямо а-ля `($this->_helpers[$name])($args)` (это внутри `__call`)

Comment: @teran, я тоже думала, что можно также как и со свойствами, просто сохранить в массив. Просто мне казалось, что есть другой способ)

Comment: если придумаете - поделитесь :)

Comment: @teran, спасибо большое) обязательно поделюсь)